# Dask in the python REPL - is it possible to set a progress bar?

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I am using Dask in the python REPL. Is it possible to set a progress bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is. Using the Progress bar from Dask Diagnostics.
See link: http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/diagnostics-local.html

```
from dask.diagnostics import ProgressBar

a = da.random.normal(size=(10000, 10000), chunks=(1000, 1000))
res = a.dot(a.T).mean(axis=0)

pbar = ProgressBar()
pbar.register()

out = res.compute()
```